# Convert bitmap image objects in ms word 2010 to images

Tags: microsoft-office, images, microsoft-word-2010

I have a MS Word document which has some images and text. Some of the images are of `bitmap image object` types. When i copy them and try to paste them in any editor say gmail compose editor they are not rendered. Other images are being copied and rendered. Is there some way i can convert those bitmap image objects to jpg or png inside Word. One way i found was to copy the bitmap image and use `Paste Special` and then choose a format like jpg or png. Is there an easier way? Or is there some way i can convert all bitmap images in the document to png? I am using MS- Word 2010. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Save your file in `.docx` format, if you haven't already.
2. Rename `foobar.docx` to `foobar.zip`.
3. Open the zip file, and browse to the `word/media` folder. 
   Your images should appear there as distinct files, which you can then copy out.